# Docker CMD can't find files installed with Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

COPY /entrypoint.sh .

COPY /script.sh /home/

RUN chmod +x /home/script.sh

VOLUME ["/home/volume/bla"]

EXPOSE 3677 3678

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["sh /home/script.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo $@
exec "$@"
```

My script.sh

```
echo "yay ... hello docker world";
```

I build the project
`docker build /home/project/docker/ -t root/project`

Then I run it `docker run --user root -it --name project-container root/project`

It logs `$@` then `exec $@`

```
sh /home/script.sh
/entrypoint.sh: line 25: /sh /home/script.sh: No such file or directory
```

Why does it not find the script? this is driving me nuts.

Also tried: `CMD ["/usr/bin/sh /home/script.sh"]` in the Dockerfile but I get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `CMD` in your dockerfile should look like

```
CMD ["sh", "/home/script.sh"]
```

and you can remove the `ENTRYPOINT` line